# JDBC caching on Glassfish

Tags: jdbc, glassfish

I am running into `OutOfMemoryError` on a long running background process on Glassfish. Memory analysis has shown that at the time the error is thrown 50% of the heap is dedicated to instances of `com.mysql.JDBC4ResultSet` (28.1%) and `com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl` (22.1%).

My code is structured on the assumption that my JDBC objects will be Garbage Collected once they loose scope however this is obviously not the case. I originally did this using JPA but the memory load exploded so I reverted to JDBC but I am still getting enormous memory leaks consisting of references to JDBC Statements & ResultSets.

So I am wondering if Glassfish is caching these queries and how I can disable that, the data objects are quite large and I really don't need them to be cached.

I have included below the structure of my code consisting of one class and two methods (modified for brievity).

```
@Stateless
public class WSDFileCollector implements Collector {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    @Asynchronous
    public void run(final CollectorEntity collector) throws SQLException {

        final Connection connection = em.unwrap(Connection.class);
        final String table = "tmp_sat_" + collector.getSite().getId();
        final String column = "filename";
        try {
            // Create temporary table
            // Scan files & folders under a given directory.
            // Load filenames into MySQL Temporary table.

            final Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            final ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery("SELECT filename FROM temporary_table WHERE filename NOT IN (SELECT filename FROM existing_files");
            while (results.next()) {
                final File file = new File(collector.getPath(), results.getString("filename"));
                if (file.isFile()) {
                    extractAndSave(file, collector);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            // Delete temporary table
        }
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    private void extractAndSave(final File file, final CollectorEntity collector) {
        final Connection connection = em.unwrap(Connection.class);
        try {
            // Begin a transaction
            // INSERT new file into existing_files

            // Scan the file, extract data and insert into multiple database tables.

            // Commit transaction
        } catch (final SQLException | FileNotFoundException ex) {
            // Rollback transaction
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've unwrapped the connection from the entity manager and thus completely take over the control over the resources in your own hands, you should explicitly close them *yourself* in the `finally` block of the very same `try` block as where they're been acquired as per the following standard JDBC idiom.

```
// Declare resources.
Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;

try {
    // Acquire resources.
    connection = getConnectionSomehow();
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);

    // ...
} finally {
    // Close resources in reversed order.
    if (resultSet != null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
    if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
    if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
}
```

Otherwise they will remain in an opened state and indeed leak away in both the server and the DB.

Comment: Your on the money as always BalusC. I had no idea that ResultSet and Statement needed to be closed. Thanks.